# Linked list - not linking

Tags: c, linked-list

This seems pretty straightforward. Create a linked list, populate it with some structs and than print them out.
However for some reason only first entry stored in head variable is created and nothing else. The program get caught in a loop in the addHorse() method. Specifically the else part. I looks like first entry has itself stored in the *next variable but I specifically changed it to NULL when I created it.

Any idea what I did wrong<

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>



typedef struct horse{
char name[12];
char color[10];
int price;
struct horse *next;
}HORSE;

HORSE *head  = NULL;

void addHorse(HORSE * newHorse) {
    HORSE *lastHorse;
    if(head == NULL){
        head = newHorse;
        head->next = NULL;
    }
    else{
        lastHorse = head;
        while(lastHorse->next != NULL){
            lastHorse = lastHorse->next;
        }
    lastHorse->next = newHorse;
    }

    newHorse->next = NULL;
}

HORSE *create(){
    HORSE *hr;
    hr=(HORSE *) malloc (sizeof (HORSE));
    if (hr==NULL){
        printf("spatne");
        exit (-1);
    }
    hr->next=NULL;

    return hr;
}

void makeHorses(){
    int i, p, k;
    HORSE *newHorse;
    p = 40;
    k = 10;
    newHorse = create();
    for(i = 0;i <= p;i++){
        if((i%3) == 0){
            strcpy(newHorse->name,"semik");
            if(i<=k){
                newHorse->price = 20000;
            }
            else{
                newHorse->price = 6000;
            }
        }
        else{
            strcpy(newHorse->name,"hryzal");
            if(i<=k){
                newHorse->price = 20000;
            }
            else{
                newHorse->price = 6000;
            }
        }
        strcpy(newHorse->color, "black");
        newHorse->next = NULL;
        addHorse(newHorse);
    }
}

void printHorses(){
    HORSE *firstHorse;
    firstHorse = head;
    while((firstHorse->next) != NULL){
        printf("%s\n", firstHorse->name);
        printf("%s\n", firstHorse->color);
        printf("%d\n", firstHorse->price);
        firstHorse = firstHorse->next;
    }
}

int main(){   
    makeHorses();
    printHorses();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you use a debugger? Step through your code? Compare actual variable contents with expected values? Your code looks bogus. Take the time to go through it step by step.

Comment: move 
newHorse = create();
inside for loop.

Comment: Fix formatting, this will remove (make obvious) half of all bugs.

Comment: @DrKoch: OCD-me just did that. For free :/

Comment: @Gauthier who is OCD-me??

Comment: @DrKoch: it was self derision, I fixed the indentation and found myself quite ridiculous for doing so, victim of OCD (obsessive compulsive disorder).

Comment: Just noticed that I didn't translate some variables. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do `newHorse = create();` in each iteration of for loop in `makeHorses()` function.

With your code, you are adding same node multiple times.

Comment: Thank you that did trick. I guess its official: I SUCK AT PROGRAMMING.